# Problems with Many to Many relation in Hibernate ORM with Panache in Quarkus

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am building a rest api about indie games and their developers. I am having troubles implementing the many to many relation between games and developers.

Here is my rest endpoint for posting a game by a developer:

```
@POST
@PermitAll
@Path("/{developerId}/games")
public Response postGameByDeveloper(@PathParam("developerId") long developerId, GameDTO gameDTO) {
    DeveloperEntity developerEntity = developerService.getDeveloper(developerId);

    if (developerEntity == null) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }

    System.out.println(gameDTO.toString());

    developerService.postGameByDeveloper(developerId, GameDTO.Converter.toEntity(gameDTO));

    return Response.ok(GameDTO.Converter.toDTOList(developerEntity.getGames())).build();
}
```

This is the repository method that stores the game:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void postGameByDeveloper(long developerId, GameEntity gameEntity) {
    DeveloperEntity developer = findById(developerId);
    if (developer == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Developer with ID " + developerId + " not found.");
    }

    developer.getGames().add(gameEntity);
    getEntityManager().merge(gameEntity);
}
```

And this is the many to many relationship in my entites:

In DeveloperEntity.java

```
@ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE
})
@JoinTable(name = "developer_game",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "developer_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "game_id")
)
private Set<GameEntity> games = new HashSet<>();
```

In GameEntity.java:

```
@ManyToMany()
private Set<DeveloperEntity> developers = new HashSet<>();
```

When I post a game to the api endpoint I get this issue:

"details": "Error id 3c9979df-cbce-4435-902b-02e562ce353b-5, org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: io.quarkus.arc.ArcUndeclaredThrowableException: Error invoking subclass method"

What am I missing here? I have tried many ways to solve this issue but I just can't get it to work properly.

Comment: What happens if you remove the last line where you call merge() ? And are you also setting the developer to the GameEntity ?